# settings control by keyboard impossible?

Tags: keyboard, shortcuts, settings, gnome-control-center

### situation:

Having a bluetooth mouse on Ubuntu 20.04, I sometimes attach it to another computer.
When wanting to re-attach, one has to **go to settings without an easily reachable mouse** and take the necessary steps.

### problem:

While access to the main menus is possible by `<Super>F10` and settings can be opened up,
**steering through settings using only the keyboard seems impossible**.

### Questions:

- what did I miss here?
- Is it not supposed to work just by using a keyboard?